# Best way to create a flat UV Map

Tags: uv

I am wanting to create a template of a RZR, The issue is when I get to UV map some of the faces blend overlap on template which causes blurring. What would be the best way to map the below item so that all faces show on the uv while maintaining its general shape?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You probably need to add more seams. Hard to say without seeing the UV map.

Comment: Yeah I tried that made a mess haha... I can show on over a screenshare if you'd like.